# Is it possible to convert an exported list of sass variables to a TypeScript union type (NextJs/React)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, sass, next.js, react-css-modules

I am trying to export a list of colours from a .scss file and use the variable names as a list of TypeScript union types. This is so if I add a new colour in the scss file, it will automatically update the types - requiring less maintenance. The current implementation is like this:

```
// _colors.module.scss
$azure: #0070C0 ;
$white: #FFFFFF ;

:export {
  azure: $azure;
  white: $bianca;
}
```

I am creating a component which will use these colours as a prop type in NextJs, with TypeScript, working something like this:

```
//Typography.tsx

// imports colours as object
import colors from 'styles/_colors.module.scss'

type Color = keyof typeof colors;

interface TypographyProps {
  color?: Color;
  // expect the above to be equivalent to 
  // color?: 'azure' | 'white';
}

const getStyles = (color: Color) => {
  const styles: {color?: string} = {}
  styles.color = color ? colors[color] : undefined
  return styles
}

function Typography({ children, color='azure' }: TypographyProps) {
   return (
      <p
         style={getStyles(color)}
      >
      </p>
   )
}
```

The colour work as expected in regards to styling, however the TypeScript integration does not.

If I declare a colour object in the same file (or in JS and import it), it works as expected:

`(JSX attribute) TypographyProps.color?: "white" | "azure" | undefined`

But when importing from SCSS I get the following:

`(JSX attribute) TypographyProps.color?: string | number | symbol | undefined`

Please let me know if any further info is needed.